# Monitor network performance for ffmpeg streaming

Tags: performance, networking, ffmpeg, delay, jitter

I'm building up a complex network emulation and I'm trying to catch some important performance measurements.
I have mininet running on a server and I' streaming videos from one mininet host to another (with -nodisp option cause I have no GUI).

Is it possible to catch some performance measurements from ffmpeg, maybe writing them on a file?

I would like to find delay, bandwidth, maybe jitter, and so on.

Thanks everyone in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone's interested, I resolved this way:

- I moved to mp4box instead of ffmpeg to create dash chunks/manifest/.. (much better support and stability)
- I've written a no-GUI python video *player*
- I read my python player log files